# Install venv for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to create venv using python3 on Ubuntu 15.10.
I have installed python 3.4.4. 
First, I tried to install venv via pip3 (I already installed it via python2.7 but as far as I understand, for py3 I should install it again)

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

And I got `The 'pip==8.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application` error.

Next I tried to install pip3 with this command:

```
> sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and looks like it was successfully completed. But when I run

```
> pip3
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3130, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3116, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3143, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 644, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 657, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.0.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

If I run

```
> pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Does pip3 require only pip==8.0?

Answer (score 1):

Your pip is pointing to python 2.7

```
  usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

first change path

```
  export PATH=/path/to/python3:/path/to/python3/scripts-folder:/path/to/python3-pip:$PATH
```

check path

```
  echo $PATH
```

then run pip or pip3

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by another way: just runned virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 .venv3 and I got what I need. :)