# Installing venv for python3 in WSL (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv

I am trying to configure `venv` on Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu.

What I have tried:

1) Installing `venv` through `pip` (`pip3`, to be exact)

```
pip3 install venv
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement venv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for venv
```

2) Installing `venv` through `apt` and `apt-get`

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

In this case the installation seems to complete, but when I try to create a virtual environment with `python3 -m venv ./venv`, I get an error, telling me to do `apt-get install python3-venv` (which I just did!)

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/mnt/c/Users/Vicubso/.../code/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

I have also read the following posts 
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271982/install-python3-venv-module-on-linux-mint), 
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390827/install-venv-for-python3), and several others. None of these seem to solve my problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Give this approach a shot:

Install the pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Install the virtual environment:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Store your virtual environments somewhere:

```
mkdir ~/.storevirtualenvs
```

Now you should be able to create a new virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p python3 yourVenv
```

To activate:

```
source yourVenv/bin/activate
```

To exit your new virtualenv, just `deactivate`

Comment: It seems to work. But I don't know if it is the ideal solution. When I create a virtual environment with `virtualenv yourVenv` (maybe there's a typo in your answer?) It only works if I use `sudo`. Also... is there any advantage in using `virtualenv` instead of `venv`? But thanks a lot, though. At least now  I have something to continue my work.

Comment: Yep. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe). It talks about the different variations and environments to run your programs. Some of the explanation is for windows and not **linux** systems.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now have a better understanding now of all those options. I am accepting your answer as it solved my problem.

Comment: I ran into some issues with finding the correct repositories ... adding `--fix-missing` when installing `python-pip` seemed to fix things.

Comment: Some people may need to use: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 62):

Nothing here worked for me, but this did in WSL2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv whatever
```

Good luck!

Comment: Recent updates to WSL have invalidated the currently accepted answer, I think. This worked for me via wsl.exe while the other suggestions gave lots of errors.

Comment: And you need sudo for the commands that you have mentioned. It works for me but not the previous commands anymore. +1

Comment: Worked for me with WSL2. I can't stress you enough just like the above comment: use sudo on apt-get.

Comment: works perfectly on WSL2. (tip: just use python3 -v  as python could be updated to new version by the time you try it.. in our case we had python 3.10)

Answer (score 16):

This was more of a headache than it needed to be. It seems that it relates to WSL<->Windows file system mapping issues. [This blog post](http://www.greenworm.net/stuff/st/2020/02/29/wsl-and-virtualenvs.html) perhaps describes it better, but the net is you need to store additional metadata with files on a particular mount, as described [in this MS devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/).

I fixed the issue by running:

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

After which I was able to create python venv without needing to sudo.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, thanks a bunch!

Comment: A combination of this, and the response by trpt4him helped.  Thanks!  Any way have WSL start up so I don't have to do this every time I want to create a new env?

Comment: Wow black magic

Answer (score 7):

The error occurs when you're in `/mnt/XXX` (under Windows part).

Switch to Linux part by `cd` and run `python3 -m venv ./venv` again and that should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message, I have WSL(Ubuntu) installed on my computer, finally I found this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/web-frameworks#open-a-wsl---remote-window
Ironically the only difference from what I was using as command was the name, I was using venv, then I run the command again using .venv so that the files become hidden files instead, and it worked. Hopefully it'll help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install also python3.8-venv via
`sudo apt install python3.8-venv`

this fixed the problem for me.