# I am unable to create a new virtualenv in ubuntu?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So, I installed virtualenv in ubuntu terminal. I installed using the following commands:

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
```

But when I try creating a new virtualenv using:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'virtualenv.create.via_global_ref.builtin.cpython.mac_os' has no attribute 'CPython2macOsArmFramework'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to use `virtualenv`. You can use this:

```
python3 -m venv ./some_env
```

Comment: before:
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
after:
python3.9 -m venv venv

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar experience. The reason for this is that I did it by installing two virtualenv with apt and pip3. This seems to be a known bug (See also [here](https://techoverflow.net/2022/02/03/how-to-fix-tox-attributeerror-module-virtualenv-create-via_global_ref-builtin-cpython-mac_os-has-no-attribute-cpython2macosarmframework/))

Another way a second (or third) instance of virtualenv might have come to your system is via `sudo pip install`.

So, to be sure you only have one version, you can remove all of them:

```
pip3 upip3 uninstall virtualenvninstall virtualenv
sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv
sudo apt purge python3-virtualenv
```

...and then pick one and re-install it (my preference is userspace `pip install virtualenv`).

Comment: I got the error while updating dependencies with poetry. Uninstalling `virtualenv` package that was present in the venv (probably as subdependency of other packages) solved the issue for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the one that actually addresses the problem in the question.

Answer (score 4):

First off, just one of

```
sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
```

should do. You do not need the `pip` command if the `apt` installation worked.

Second, you should be able to create one where you can write:

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ mkdir venvdemo
edd@rob:/tmp$ cd venvdemo/
edd@rob:/tmp/venvdemo$ virtualenv -p python3 venv
created virtual environment CPython3.9.5.final.0-64 in 162ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/tmp/venvdemo/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/edd/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.4, pkg_resources==0.0.0, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.34.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
edd@rob:/tmp/venvdemo$ 
edd@rob:/tmp/venvdemo$ ls -a 
.  ..  venv
edd@rob:/tmp/venvdemo$ ls -a venv/
.  ..  bin  .gitignore  lib  pyvenv.cfg
edd@rob:/tmp/venvdemo$
```

(and I did this on an Ubuntu machine).

Third, something is still *very* wrong because with Ubuntu you should not get an error message for `CPython2macOsArmFramework`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `virtualenv` anymore. Since Python3.3, you can use [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create virtual environments.

```
python3 -m venv ./desired_name_of_env
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me for recent Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy:

start with installing pip:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try installing virtual env:

```
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
```

create virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when creating the environment.

However, I was trying to create it through my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 LST.

After some research, someone in the comment section of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61528738/18341787) post suggested adding `sudo` when creating the environment could resolve the issue, which works for me.

```bash
sudo virtualenv venv
```

Now, I am not sure why adding sudo works. My guess is that without superuser permission, WSL cannot create a folder for the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, use:

```
sudo virtualenv venv
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know that many people use `venv` nowdays but the functionality of just using `mkvirtualenv` to make a new virtual environment and just using `workon` to get a list of available envs and  working on them has prompted me to stick to virtualenv itself.

What worked for me in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

`sudo apt install virtualenv`

Don't use `pip install virtualenv` as it does not automatically set the path.

Create a directory to store all your virtual envs using:

`mkdir .virtualenv`

Install the virtualenvwrapper using:

`pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

Modify your .bashrc file by adding the following commands:

`export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs`

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`

`source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`

Source the .bashrc file using :
`. ~/.bashrc` in your terminal.

Restart your terminal and create a virtual environment using:

`mkvirtualenv name-of-env`

The environment is activated upon creation and appears as
`(name-of-environment)user@sys-name:~$`

To deactivate the environment just use :
`deactivate` in your terminal.

Now you can access the list of environments using `workon` and activate them by simply using:
`workon name-of-environment`